# Java - Reading information off of a text file

Tags: java

information.txt:

```
//FNAME LNAME ADDRESS CITY STATE OCCUPATION

John Doe 1234 North Road New York New York Student
Joe Tommy 5678 South Lane Buffalo New York Teacher
```

I am trying to use Java to read a file (a text file to be exact) and get information based on the position of the text within the file.

Say I call a method to get a person's address from the file, I would want "1234 North Road" only. But let's say I want their name, so I call another method that would give "John Doe". Problem is, I do not know how to get information based on it's position in the file.

I'm thinking about a BufferedReader, but I don't know exactly what that does. All help is appreciated.

Comment: I can't read that, since it's impossible to know where each field starts and ends, so it would be impossible for a program to read it too.

Comment: A buffered reader can read text files fine, you could read the file a line at a time.  But the question would be how is your file delimited?  Is it tab delimited, or are the fields a fixed character length?  If it is space delimited, you have problems as your data fields have spaces already.  Try something and update the question with specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is add a separator in the text file. Example.

John Doe | 1234 North Road | New York New York | Student

Joe Tommy | 5678 South Lane | Buffalo  New York | Teacher

Example Code:

```
        String dirFile = "C:\\myfile.txt";
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(dirFile);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
               String[] sep = line.split("\\|");
               String name = sep[0].trim();
               String address = sep[1].trim();
               String cities = sep[2].trim();
               String category = sep[3].trim();
        }
```